# Using Stencil JS component locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-component, stenciljs

tl;dr: how to use stenciljs components without publishing to npm: copy and paste `dist` folder from original stencil project build, then use `dist/yourComponent/yourComponent.esm.js` and `dist/esm/yourComponent.js` in new project (??)

Hey, self-taught noob here learning some web dev. Stencil JS sounds cool. So do some tutorials etc and then want to just play around with stencil components just on locally hosted projects. All the stencil build/output documentation seems to be geared towards putting your components -even just for your own use- on npm. Not really necessary in a case like mine, and even if you're a professional developer, you should have the option not to publish to npm if you so choose, right? Ok, so you `npm run build` your component, and then just copy and paste the entire `dist` folder from your stencil build, and just drop it into your little play project. But what `<script>` source do you use?? So in `dist > yourComponent` folder, you'll see something like `yourComponent.esm.js`, and using this file *seems* to be working BUT this is a bit different than what you will see on your original stencil component -if you look there, you will see another script file as well, ie.

```
 <script type="module" src="/build/yourComponent.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="/build/yourComponent.js"></script>
```

so I assume the second script is a backup in case there are any issues using ecmascript modules (hence the `.esm.js` vs `.js`). But then I found `yourComponent.js` in a different subfolder,

`dist > esm`! So, I've included it too and I just want to make sure that this should be all I need to properly use stencil components without publishing to npm. Thanks!

Comment: So you say Stencil is always loading its JS file _twice_?

Comment: Well, there is a 'nomodule' script as well as a '.esm.js', so I assume it's a browser support thing in case there are any issues with js modules (ie polyfill)

Answer (score 1):

The following approach works for me:

*stencil.config.ts*:

```yaml
  ...

  outputTargets: [
    {
      type: 'dist',
      esmLoaderPath: '../loader',
    },

    ...
  ],

  ...  

  bundles: [
    {
      components:
        [
          'my-component'
        ]
    },
  ],

  ...
```

Then, I'm running the `npm start` command for my component:

```
> my-component@0.0.1 start
> stencil build --dev --watch --serve

.....

[16:05.8]  build, my-component, dev mode, started ...
[16:05.9]  transpile started ...
[16:07.4]  transpile finished in 1.50 s
[16:07.4]  copy started ...
[16:07.4]  generate lazy started ...
[16:07.5]  copy finished (16 files) in 98 ms
[16:11.3]  generate lazy finished in 3.94 s
[16:11.4]  build finished, watching for changes... in 5.52 s

[16:11.4]  http://localhost:3333/
```

And after that, I am able to use this component in another project locally:

```html
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:3333/build/my-component.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="http://localhost:3333/build/my-component.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, just curious why you use the build folder instead of the dist folder, is there any difference?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure, I've been always using the build folder

Comment: There's probably no difference, but I have seen a couple other ways: 1. like I said, grabbing the 'dist' folder, and 2. just grabbing the 'yourComponent' folder from the 'dist' folder. It probably depends on what you're using the component for, and I wish the documentation could include some alternatives to publishing to npm...

Comment: Probably these two ways are the same in the case of component local testing